# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: sort(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array - Looping through Word Press Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, sorting, php-8

I have a taxonomy in Word Press known as "Job Title", I want to loop through the posts and display the job title in a Select field in alphabetical order, this is my code -

```
<select name="jobTitle" id="jobTitleFilter">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Job Title</option>
    <?php foreach ( get_terms( 'job_title',  array() ) as $job_title ) : ?>
        <?php sort( $job_title ); ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_html( $job_title->term_id); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $job_title->name ); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

The code works on PHP 7 with errors, but on PHP 8.0.30 I get this fatal error -

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: sort(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, WP_Term givenin template-partner-job-postings.php on line 26

On PHP 7 in Query Monitor I see this error -

sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

`php_sort()` is expecting an array not an object, so I fixed this by sorting the data within the Wordpress `get_terms()` -

````
<select name="jobTitle" id="jobTitleFilter">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Job Title</option>
    <?php foreach ( get_terms( 'job_title',  ['orderby' => 'name'] ) as $job_title ) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_html( $job_title->term_id); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $job_title->name ); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```
````